# Number recursion

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I think it is not called as in the title, but anyway, that is it below. Can anyone please explain the magics?

1/99 = .01010101010101010101
1/999 = .00100100100100100100
1/9999 = .00010001000100010001
1/99999 = .00001000010000100001
1/999999 = .00000100000100000100
1/9999999 = .00000010000001000000
1/999999999 = .00000000100000000100
1/9999999999 = .00000000010000000001

Comment: Why leave out $1/9 = .111111111$?

Comment: Because I stepped into this calculating percents. It is just for historical reasons :)

Comment: $1/9 = 11.11\ldots\%$.

Comment: You are right, then I should put also n in { 0, -1, -2, ..}. Apart from the singularity, which bumps you in the negative integers below -1, the game seems to work also like this. Convergence to -1 on this side, which is what I searched, because I wanted to approximate 100% with this game. A lot of fun with simple ingredients, yeah @MDJ? What about summing on n positive or negative? n positive looks funnier to me.

Comment: It looks like binary code, by the way, who knows what happens if you make it run on some processor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ \dfrac{1}{10^n-1}\, =\, \dfrac{1}{10^n}\, \dfrac{1}{1-10^{-n}}\, =\, 10^{-n} (1 + 10^{-n} + 10^{-2n}+\,\cdots\,)\ $ via [geometric power series.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)

Answer (score 0):

There are all special cases of a more general pattern.  Whenever $a>1$, we have

$$\frac1a + \frac1{a^2} + \frac1{a^3} + \frac1{a^4} + \ldots = \frac1{a-1}.$$

For example, you may be familiar with the fact $\frac12 + \frac14 + \frac18 + \ldots = 1$, which is the case of the formula above when $a=2$.

Now $0.01010101\ldots = \frac1{100} + \frac1{10,000} + \frac1{1,000,000}+\ldots$, so this is an instance of the formula for $a={100}$. In this case the right-hand side $\frac{1}{a-1} = \frac1{99}$.  Your other examples are similar.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't vote up, but I won't forget the help!